# How to know the account used for google sign in ios sdk

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, google-ios-vision

I have integrated the google sign in sdk in ios but I forgot from which account I did it.

I have the configuration file and client id and reverse client id

So how can I know which google account I used to create an sign in.

Answer (score 0):

For getting user details of logged in user you can use this API

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/profile
```

for more details refer this [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile)